# What source book or books can I find information focusing on Sigil?

Tags: planescape

My group is playing using Pathfinder rules, but really want to transport themselves to Planescape's city of Sigil.

Regardless of D&D Edition or Campaign Setting, what source books are there that focus on Sigil that I should familiarize myself with so I can be ready to GM once they have managed to get there?

Answer (score 13):

Please do make yourself familiar with the Planescape setting itself via [Planescape Campaign Setting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planescape_Campaign_Setting) boxed set.

After you do, the book you want is [In the Cage: A Guide to Sigil](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-cage.htm). You might also want to take a look at [The Factol’s Manifesto](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-factol.htm).

Comment: Also "Uncaged - Faces of Sigil"

Answer (score 2):

I have recently found this [full planescape index](http://www.rilmani.org/psIndex.txt). From there you can look up references to Sigil, and locations within and cross reference the books.

Additionally, I found an [interactive map of Sigil](https://nether-whisper.ru/rp/planescape/map-of-sigil/) with useful book references there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Planar Handbook is a D&D 3.x splatbook that contains a small section on Sigil. (Pages 141 to 146 deal with it.)

The Manual of the Planes (p 147-152) also D&D 3.x concerns the Outlands. Sigil, also called the City of Doors, is located at the heart of the Outlands.